# OpenGL: How can I change the znear and zfar in my application?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to change the zfar and near of my application. I've tried using glFrustum (at initialization).

```
glFrustum(0.0, SCRWIDTH, SCRHEIGHT, 0.0, 1.0, 1000.0);
```

But whatever value I put in, the objects still disappear when I move back. I've also tried using a negative znear and far but again nothing changed.

I don't want to scale.

Comment: are you using fixed function or shaders?

Comment: I would have to look at the rest of your code to make a more accurate suggestion. Make sure to call `glMatrixMode()` with `GL_PROJECTION` followed by `glLoadIdentity()` before invoking `glFrustum()`. Then make sure your GL drawing function calls `glMatrixMode()` with `GL_MODELVIEW` followed by `glLoadIdentity()` before you execute any translation/rotation/scale operation. **Remember**: `glTranslate*()` takes a negative number for the Z axis, but `glFrustum()` does not.

Comment: Objects will inevitably disappear no matter what value you use; you have a finite depth range. You usually want to keep zNear and zFar somewhat close together (e.g. not 0.002f and 20000000.0f) because in addition to defining the *range* of depths representable, those two values also negatively impact *precision*. You can have an extremely large range, but then you cannot resolve differences in depth between objects that are close together. I should point out, I am not referring to the *depth range* in screen space (`glDepthRange (...)`); just the range of Z values before they are clipped.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, i'll look into what is the best solution for what I'm trying to do, thanks for the info!